# Change text size of file names within one folder only

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, desktop-customization

Is it possible to change the size of the text of filenames within a single folder -> i.e. not changing text size for every folder on the PC ?

I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same thing a month ago, but no. Microsoft set the size of the icons to be constant for all. A third-party program cannot do this too.

Here are two workarounds that can...kind of fix your problem:

**1st workaround**: You can pin a file/folder in the Start Menu, where it will look bigger.

**2nd workaround:** You can change the size of all icons by pressing **Ctrl**+**MouseWheelScroll**

Comment: It's actually the text of each filename rather than it's icon that I want to change. I already have the icons at max size that Ctrl+MouseWheelScroll allows. Thanks anyway for the reply.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to do this as a joke on one of my friends, but its impossible for now.